# (Dual boot) Windows 7 asks for recovery key after update

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, bitlocker, tpm

I have an [HP Zbook 15 G3](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/workstations/zbook-15.html) with 2 x [Samsung SM961 nVME SSD](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/ssd/client-ssd/MZVKW512HMJP/)'s installed.

One SSD has Windows 7 Ent installed and is protected by BitLocker.

The second SSD has Windows 10 Ent installed but is not (currently) protected by BitLocker.

Whenever I install any 'substantial' updates (e.g Creators Update) on Windows 10, upon booting into Windows 7 I am asked for my BitLocker recovery key. Fortunately, the BitLocker key is always<sup>1</sup> as expected and I can enter my known recovery key and [run through the usual procedure](https://knowledge.zomers.eu/misc/Pages/Solve-having-to-enter-your-BitLocker-key-every-time-at-Windows-boot.aspx) to stop being prompted for it on every boot.

How can I stop these updates requiring me to go through this rigmarole?

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>On one occasion the BitLocker key was not what I was expecting. I ended up having to perform a fresh Windows 7 install. That was quite frustrating</sub></sup>

Comment: Suspend BitLocker then install the feature update using the appropriate mounted ISO within Windows, then resume BitLocker protection after it the upgrade is done. Until the most recent feature update 1803 this was more/less required if BitLocker protection was enabled on Windows 10 (although it was automated)

Comment: @Ramhound It is often (usually) the case that the install happens without my knowledge, so I don't have the opportunity to suspend BitLocker

Comment: You should then configure your system so Feature Updates are deferred, and install them on your schedule, the most recent one took over a month and a half to be pushed to all machines over Windows Update.  You won't be able to avoid suspending BitLocker when you install a feature update.